# Can this C++ code for growing an array possibly break?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I finally decided to learn `C++` for good and I ran into the code below in a book that grows an array size. The function takes a pointer to an array with its original size and returns a new one with double the size.

```
int *doubleArraySize(int *p_array, int *p_size) {
    *p_size *= 2;

    int *p_new_array = new int[*p_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < *p_size; i++)
        p_new_array[i] = p_array[i];

    delete[] p_array;
    return p_new_array;
}
```

By the time we reach the for loop the value of `*p_size` has already been doubled. This means (at least to me) that when we access `p_array[i]` we end up in areas of the memory that do not belong to `p_array`. Is this an issue? Can this code ever crash?? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: don't you need a malloc at some point?

Comment: @njzk2 In C++? When you can use `new` too?

Comment: "Can this code ever crash"? Probably, or maybe not, or maybe only at full moon :) Point is, it's undefined behavior, unless `new` throws and you never get in the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the standard library for this? You know things like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector`?

Comment: This code have a lot of troubles: what if any pointers are null? What if `p_array` is not constructed with `new[]`?

Comment: Please don't hesitate to sh/name the book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is not safe code. You copy from `p_array` beyond its limits (if it was the previous `*p_size`). While it *probably* will not crash, it's still *undefined behavior*.

I have two suggestions:

1. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)!
2. If not, then at least use [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) for the copying (with the correct size of course).

Answer (score 4):

Your biggest problem is that you're multiplying `*p_size` by two too early, so you read past the end of the old array in the `for` loop.

You can resolve this issue by postponing the multiplication to after the copy:

```
int extend_arr(int *old, size_t *sz)
{
    int *newarr = new int[*sz * 2];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < *sz; i++)
        newarr[i] = old[i];

    *sz *= 2;
    return newarr;
}
```

An the usual warning: **why don't you use `std::vector` instead?** With vector, you can just `resize()` it and let the standard library do the hard work.

Comment: Also because of the early adjustment, if `operator new` throws an exception, `*p_size` has the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

**new** can fail and throw an exception.

There is also a risk that the pointers may be NULL.